# Android MediaPlayer volume scale?

Tags: android, media-player, volume

According to the docs the `MediaPlayer setVolume(float, float)` needs to be given a logarithmically scaled value:

> Note that the passed volume values are raw scalars. UI controls should
>   be scaled logarithmically.

I was wondering how to do this? Should I just give a `log(volume)` to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give values between 0.0f (mute) and 1.0f (full volume)

Comment: So the volume scale is linear?

Comment: No, but this doean't matter. Volume units are decibels, that are logatirmic based (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel). So just use it as linear :-)

Answer (score 0):

For [Android MediaPlayer.setVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume%28float,%20float%29), searching the web seems to show 0.0f for no sound, 1.0f for full sound.